# Build a GQL with "IN' query for ReferenceProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

class Message(db.Model):

```
user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, required=True, collection_name='Message_set')  
text = db.TextProperty(required=True)
```

I tried this but I'm getting BadValueError on the gql statement.

users = []

users.append(userA)

users.append(userB)

users.append(userC)

messages = Message.gql('Where user In :users', users=users).fetch(100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell without the complete stacktrace (please?), but I would guess that IN doesn't like being passed entities rather than keys. Try this:

```
users = [userA.key(), userB.key(), userC.key()]
messages = Message.gql("WHERE user in :users", users=users).fetch(100
```

Answer (score 2):

The `IN` operator in GQL is actually synthesized by application-level Python code as a loop doing a series of `=` fetches and concatenating them -- it's not really part of the underlying store's capabilities and so is unfortunately subject to some limitations (and its performance is never particularly good). I'm not sure it was a great design decision to include it in the Python API (I believe it was not duplicated in the Java API), but, there you are. (Btw, the `!=` operator has similar issues, too).

I'm not sure why in particular this should interfere with your intended usage, but I suspect it's due to the "query" object being an instance of datastore.MultiQuery rather than plain datastore.Query -- what happens if you do in your own application-level Python code what the GAE-supplied application level Python code normally does?  See in your SDK sources file google/appengine/api/datastore.py, specifically the MultiQuery class -- in the end it boils down to doing all the separate queries and merging their results (in sorted order, if required, but that doesn't seem to be the case here).

Answer (score 1):

with this models:

```
class MyUsuario(db.Model):
    nombre=db.StringProperty(required=True)

class Message(db.Model):
    MyUsuario = db.ReferenceProperty(MyUsuario, required=True, collection_name='Message_set')  
    text = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

This code works:

```
from modelos import MyUsuario, Message
from google.appengine.ext import db

usuarios=MyUsuario.all()

userA=usuarios[0]
userB=usuarios[1]
userC=usuarios[2]

usuarios= []

usuarios.append(userA.key())
usuarios.append(userB.key())
usuarios.append(userC.key())

messages = db.GqlQuery('select * from Message Where MyUsuario In :usuari', usuari=usuarios)

for message in messages:
    print message.text
```

I saw the awnser [in this google groups post](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/4a06db5c894285f8)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want a list of users' keys?  try users.append(userA.key()).  The value of the user referenceproperty is a key to a user entity.